# jQuery select multiple same attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want select DOMs using jQuery.

HTML code

```
<li>
  <span class="node>
    <span class="con"></span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">abc</a>
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="node>
    <span class="con"></span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">def</a>
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="node>
    <span class="con"></span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="low">zwc</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

I want select "check" class span DOMs what have "a tag" has "high" title in same level.

I tried to click that DOMs using this query:

```
$('a[title="high"]').each(function() {
  $(this).prev().prev().click();
})
```

but this code have only first match value.

How can I select all DOMs?

---

My mistake. I want "check" not "con". Thanks.

The point of this question is "all" DOMs what have "high" title attr should be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.closest().find()`

```
$('a[title="high"]').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.node').find('.con').click();
})
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/otxnjq3f/1/)

Comment: This code is working but return only first match. All DOMs what have a "high" title should be clicked.

Comment: @RobertMoon did you check the demo?? Its already returned all not just first

Comment: Oh yes, the demo work well. I think there is a code block loop after click event. I'll find that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out elements from a set based on condition.

```
// Get all spans having class `con`
$('span.con').filter(function () {
    // If this element has anchor element sibling with `high` as Title
    // then return true, else return false
    return $(this).siblings('a[title="high"]').length;
}).css('color', 'green');
```

```js
$('span.con').filter(function() {
  return $(this).siblings('a[title="high"]').length;
}).css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">First</span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">abc</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">Second</span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">def</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">Third</span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <img>
    <a title="low">zwc</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.prev().prev()` use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the items in the same level and filter with `.con`.

```
$('a[title="high"]').each(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.con').click();
});
```

> If you want to know why actually your code is not working, you called `prev()` two times. By first one you select `img`, the second one will select `.check`. So you need to call `prev()` third time to reach `.con`. This is always confusing and may break anytime if you add more element in between. That's why this approach is not recommended.

Comment: This code return only first match. Because of my fault, your comment is right but this code is not work after I fixed that point.

Answer (score 1):

As CSS and jQuery don't have previous sibling selector, you can use General sibling selector.

You can use [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to select elements having specific attribute and then use jQuery's [`sibling()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select `span.con`.

```
$('span.check ~ a[title="high"]') // Select all anchors having `title` as "high"
                                // Which are next siblings of `span` having class of `check`
    .siblings('span.check') // Select sibling `span` having class `con`
    .css('color', 'green');
```

The selector `$('span.check ~ a[title="high"]')` will select anchor elements, to get the `span`, use `siblings`.

```js
$('span.check ~ a[title="high"]')
  .siblings('span.check')
  .each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'green').click();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">First</span>
    <span class="check">First Check</span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">abc</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">Second</span>
    <span class="check">Second Check</span>
    <img>
    <a title="high">def</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="node">
    <span class="con">Third</span>
    <span class="check">Third Check</span>
    <img>
    <a title="low">zwc</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As your explain, I wrote a code like this : $('span.check ~ a[title="high"]').siblings('span.check').click(); but this code check only first match. All DOMs should be checked.

Comment: @RobertMoon You can iterate over the collection using `each` and use `.click` inside it.

Comment: Oh yes, I did.
$('span.node ~ a[title="high"]').each(function () {
        $(this).siblings('span.check').click();
});
But not work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is working fine. See I tried this,
HTML :

```
<li>
<span class="node>
<span class="con"></span>
<span class="check" onclick="console.log('span :'+1);"></span>
<img onclick="console.log('img :'+1);">
<a id = "m1" title="high" onclick="console.log('a :'+1);">abc</a>
</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="node>
<span class="con"></span>
<span class="check" onclick="console.log('span :'+2);"></span>
<img onclick="console.log('img :'+2);">
<a id = "m2" title="high" onclick="console.log('a : '+2);">def</a>
</span>
</li>
<li>
<span class="node>
<span class="con"></span>
<span class="check" onclick="console.log('span : low');"></span>
<img onclick="console.log('img : low');">
<a id = "m3" title="low" onclick="console.log('low');">zwc</a>
</span>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
$('a[title="high"]').each(function() {
        // if you want to click all <a>
        $(this).click();
        // if you want to click all <img>
        $(this).prev().click();
        // if you want to click all <span> having class check
        $(this).prev().prev().click();
    });});
```

Console:

```
a :1
img :1
span :1
a : 2
img :2
span :2
```